# How to create a continuous spiral function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to make a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that looks like a spiral. The motivation being that I want to create a spiral-looking object in a program I'm making and I need to define a continuous function to create it. So far I managed to come up with this:

$$
f(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} &\quad\operatorname{mod}\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{\pi}{2},\ \pi\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \\
       \,\text{g(x,y)} &\quad\text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}
$$

I have two requirements on the $g$ function:

1. $f$ has to be continuous (and thus $g$ has to be too)
2. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}: g(x,y) < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \text{ or } \operatorname{mod}\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{\pi}{2},\ \pi\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

If I didn't need the first, then it would be pretty easy as I could simply use $g(x,y) = -1$. But I can't do that. I have managed to create a sort of 2D analogue of how I would like the $g$ function to look like:

$h(x) = 2\cdot\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)-3\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)+2\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,2\right)\right)^{2}$

[image: h function visualised]

with the local maxima of the $h$ function acting like the local maxima of $f$. However, I have no idea how to convert this function to the 3D spiral-like function $f$ or how to make something similar. Can anyone tell me how to find such a function $g$ or at least give me a hint on how I could find it myself?

Comment: Is your $\mathrm{mod}$ function like $\operatorname{mod}(x,m) = x - m \left\lfloor \frac{x}{m} \right\rfloor$?

Comment: How can you explicitly make a spiral function using Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @aschepler yes, that's the mod function that I mean.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You create it using the equation that I gave as a condition in the piecewise function $f$. Here is how it looks if you don't believe me: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e8ea28l2la

Comment: You misunderstand Tyma's comment. This is not a function in cartesian coordinates, since each x coordinate is being assigned very many different y values

Comment: @FShrike Note the "$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$". So we have a $z = f(x,y)$ graph. The "ridges" forming a spiral shape are described, and a function formula to fill in the "dips" between them is wanted.

Comment: This seems easier to express in polar coordinates. $f = h(r-\theta)$ would be a start, except it's not continuous at the origin. Once you have something good, convert back to $x,y$ coordinates if you need to.